# How to get traded volume from tick data?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this excel data with price movement and traded volume. [image: data]

By using `mydf[mydf.columns[5]].resample('1Min').ohlc()`, I get OHLC data but don't know how to get trade volume for each minute. I have few problems in my mind:

- the tick frequency is not uniform (means for some particular minute i may have say 100 sample size and for for other it may vary to 120 so .group() may not work for me)
- OHLC function takes care of the previous issue automatically as i make column G date time index
- Can i have a code which should based on "G" column do sum for volume in particular minute and then subtract it with previous minute volume data so that i get exact traded volume for that particular minute?
- Here is the input for ohlc

[image: input]

and the output i get is this,

[image: output].

I am not interested in CE as of now.

I just want another column added in this dataframe with volume for each minute value.

Comment: Is the time totally same, or the differs by microsecond? I still trying to understand why there are so many duplicate values.

Comment: yes they are not duplicates and data is changing in microsecond level sometimes only price sometimes both volume and price.  Due to only HH:MM:SS format it is looking like duplicate.

Comment: Without having the data to test, it would be difficult to debug. My suggestion is you calculate the volume first by using diff function, so the cumulative volume will changed to actual volume at the time. After that use resampler and ohlc just like what you try.

Comment: Doubt i have with doing sum using ("volume":sum(x["volume"]) for some particular length "x" is that it varies for 1 minute data. How do i make sure that it i sum for only 1 minute data.